# Você fez upload de um APK com uma assinatura inválida

Tags: android

Fui colocar meu apk no console e deu este seguinte erro.

> O envio falhou Você fez upload de um APK com uma assinatura inválida. Erro de apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures

Uso a ide android studio, assinei o apk mas contem isso na hora da de mandar,
meu manifest fica com um erro. Não sei dizer o que pode ser.

```
<meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="26.0.0-alpha1" />
```

Comment: Veja se esta resposta do SOen lhe ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816463/7762411

Comment: conseguiu resolver o problema?  @renan silva das neves

Comment: Aconteceu algo comigo quando marquei a opção de assinatura v2, quando fui assinar, observe se não foi o mesmo caso. Se sim, selecione apensaa v1 na última aba para assinar.

Comment: Você precisa assinar o apk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abaixo os passos mostrando como criar uma chave e assinar um `APK` manualmente,
lembrando que atualmente o `android-studio` também permite que você [configure o processo de compilação para assinatura automática do APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=pt-br#sign-auto)

Na barra de menus do **[android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio)**

1. Clique em <kbd>Build</kbd> → <kbd>Generate Signed APK</kbd>.
2. Selecione um módulo na lista suspensa e clique em **<kbd>Next</kbd>**.
3. Criar ou selecionar chave existente

   - **Criar** - Se você não tem uma keystore ou quer criar uma nova

     1. Clique em **<kbd>Create new</kbd>** para criar uma nova chave e repositório de chaves.
     2. Na janela **New Key Store**, forneça as informações

        - **Key store path**: local onde o repositório de chaves deve ser criado.
        - **Password**: crie e confirme uma senha segura para o `repositório de chaves`
        - **Alias**: insira um nome de identificação para a chave.
        - **Password**: crie e confirme uma senha segura para a `chave`. Essa senha deve ser diferente da senha escolhida para o `repositório de chaves`
        - **Validity (years)**: defina o período de validade da chave, em anos. A chave precisa ser válida por 25 anos ou mais para que seja possível assinar atualizações de aplicativos com a mesma chave durante a vida útil do aplicativo.
        - **Certificate**: insira algumas informações pessoais para o certificado. Essas informações não são exibidas no aplicativo, mas são incluídas no certificado como parte do APK.
        - Após preencher o formulário, clique em **<kbd>OK</kbd>**.
   - **Selecionar** - Caso você já possua uma keystore
     (Se você acabou de criar o repositório de chaves, esses campos já estarão preenchidos.)

     - **Key store path**: Selecione um repositório de chaves.
     - **Key store password**: Insira a senha do `repositório de chaves`.
     - **Key alias**: selecione a chave
     - **Key password**: Insira a senha da `chave`
     - Clique em **<kbd>Next</kbd>**
4. Na próxima janela,

   - Selecione um **destino** para os **APKs** assinados
   - **Build Type**: Selecione o tipo de compilação,
   - **Flavors**: Escolha as variações do produto (se for o caso),
   - **Signature Versions**: Marque as versões das assinatura desejada (aqui normalmente eu marco todas)
   - E clique em **<kbd>Finish</kbd>**

[image: imagem- ultima tela]
 
*imagem mostrando a ultima tela*

Fontes: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=pt-br), [en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44816463/2456894)

Answer (score 1):

abra o arquivo `/Android/gradle.properties` e inclua as seguintes informações:

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=nome-da-sua-chave.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=nome-do-seu-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

E no arquivo `android/app/build.gradle`, inclua:

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Para os que estão buscando uma saída onde o cenário é a utilização do framework Ionic, consegui corrigir isso alterando no arquivo config.xml o id da minha propriedade.

```
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" ...
```

para

```
<widget id="br.com.pedcare" ...
```