# Problema ao publica aplicativo no Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Amigos gostaria de uma ajuda, estou publicando pela primeira vez um app na play store, criei o aplicativo rodando perfeitamente, jé tenho uma conta no Google play console, criei o app mas quando vou subir o APK assinado para a produção eu recebo o seguinte aviso e não consigo prosseguir:

**APK não otimizado**

Aviso:

Este APK inclui recursos e códigos não utilizados que são enviados aos usuários. Seu app seria menor se você usasse o Android App Bundle. Quando o app não é otimizado para as configurações do dispositivo, o tamanho do download e da instalação é maior do que o necessário. Apps maiores têm taxas de instalação mais baixas e ocupam espaço nos dispositivos dos usuários.

**Resolução:**

A fim de otimizar automaticamente o app para várias configurações de dispositivos, use o Android App Bundle ou crie vários APKs.

Alguém sabe me informar como faço para resolver essa questão já tentei de tudo.

Comment: Olá, da uma olhada aqui https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle

Comment: Até li a documentação sugerida mas não consegui entender muito bem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sup>*Atualização: 07/07/2021*</sup>
> A partir de **08/2021** a Play Store passará a requerer que novos apps sejam publicados utilizando o formato AAB *(Android App Bundle)*
>
> | TIPO DE RELEASE | ANTERIOR | REQUERIDO EM 08/2021 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Novo APP | APK Target API level 29+ | **AAB** Target API level 30+ |
> | Atualização de APP | *Não requer mudança no Formato* Target API level 29+ | *Não requer mudança no Formato* Target API level 30+ |
>
> <sup>Fonte: [developers.googleblog.com](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/new-android-app-bundle-and-target-api.html)</sup>

---

Isso não me parece um problema e apenas um alerta.

A Google Play esta mostrando essa mensagem mais para informar que existe um novo método de gerar o aplicativo *(app-bundle)*, informando que esse novo método e mais eficiente que gerar um APK e etc. Isso não quer dizer que seu aplicativo esta com problema.

Pode ser que futuramente eles optem por não aceitar mais os upload de APKs, mas ainda não é o caso.

---

Para criar um *app-bundle* basta você esta em um android-studio que tenha essa opção e o processo *(pelo que testei)* parece o mesmo que gerar um APK.

Na barra de menus do android-studio clique em <kbd>Build</kbd> → <kbd>Generate Signed Bundle / APK</kbd>
<sub>Essa janela vai abrir</sub>
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione o **Android App Bundle** e clique em **<kbd>Next</kbd>**, a partir deste ponto o processo é o mesmo que [gerar um APK assinado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347177/3774), exceto pelo final que nesse novo método você não tem que selecionar os 'Signature versions', isso vai gerar um arquivo **.aab**.

> Nota: Ate o momento eu ainda não enviei nenhum aplicativo usando esse método então não sei que problemas possam ocorrer após esse ponto.

Comment: Muito obrigado Icaro